# Incorrect URL without an access token for facebook login using rauth

Tags: python, facebook, rauth

I have the code from rauth site:

```
https://github.com/litl/rauth/blob/master/examples/facebook-cli.py
```

(The code can be found at the end of this post for reference)

running the program in the command line will open a firefox window and the following message is shown from facebook site:

```
Success
SECURITY WARNING: Please treat the URL above as you would your password and do not     share it with anyone.
```

when the facebook is logged in beforehand. Even if not logged in, the facebook login window opens up and after logging in using username/password the above message is shown in firefox window.

Now the URL generated in the address bar:

```
https://www.facebook.com/connect/blank.html#_=_
```

Which is obviously an incorrect one and it gives exception from the subsequent python code.

Now how can I debug what the problem is?

Thanks

PS:

```
from rauth.service import OAuth2Service

import re
import webbrowser

# Get a real consumer key & secret from:
# https://developers.facebook.com/apps

facebook = OAuth2Service(
    client_id='xxxxxxx',
    client_secret='yyyyyyy',
    name='facebook',
    authorize_url='https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize',
    access_token_url='https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token',
    base_url='https://graph.facebook.com/')

redirect_uri = 'https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html'

params = {'scope': 'read_stream',
      'response_type': 'token',
      'redirect_uri': redirect_uri}

authorize_url = facebook.get_authorize_url(**params)

print 'Visit this URL in your browser: ' + authorize_url
webbrowser.open(authorize_url);

url_with_code = raw_input('Copy URL from your browser\'s address bar: ')
access_token = re.search('\#access_token=([^&]*)', url_with_code).group(1)
session = facebook.get_session(access_token)

user = session.get('me').json()

print 'currently logged in as: ' + user['link']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening due to a change on Facebook's end that strips the URL of the access_token programmatically. It happens on a timer, before a human could conceivably copy it out of the URL bar. The example is broken but I don't have an immediate fix for you so I might suggest you take a look at the [Flask application](https://github.com/litl/rauth/blob/master/examples/facebook) instead, which is a more practical demonstration of rauth anyway.

The relevant bit of JS you're fighting:

```
setTimeout(function() {window.history.replaceState && window.history.replaceState({}, "", "blank.html#_=_");},500);
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the prompt reply. I want to build a command line application which will scrape the relevant information of my profile like friends list etc. I can make sure it is not hacked by running in a safe environment like VM. Is this possible without resorting to a web app/server? Thanks

Comment: It's still possible, but made more difficult now: you will need to access the `authorize_url` with something like Selenium or maybe ghost.py, to handle automatically logging in and authorizing the request and then parsing the URL before it's reset by Facebook's client-side JS.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can definitely attempt either selenium, ghost.py or scrapy.

Comment: Also note that disabling JavaScript in the browser works around this for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether your q is still outstanding. I came up with a solution last year. But the code is in Powershell; therefore, it can only be used directly on Window machines. Run this script in Powershell and the stripped-out access token is printed out in the shell. Let me know whether it works on your end or not. Thx!

http://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/sas_academy/conversations/messages/591